# Split a string into an array of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My string:

```
>> pp params[:value]
"07016,07023,07027,07033,07036,07060,07062,07063,07065,07066,07076,07081,07083,07088,07090,07092,07201,07202,07203,07204,07205,07206,07208,07901,07922,07974,08812,07061,07091,07207,07902"
```

How can this become an array of separate numbers like :

```
["07016", "07023", "07033" ... ]
```

Comment: You should just give the string. Writing `params[:value]` is irrelevant to the question and is misleading.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
result = params[:value].split(/,/)
```

String#split is what you need

Answer (score 14):

Try [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165):

```
arr = "07016,07023,07027".split(",")
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that what you ask for is not an array of separate numbers, but an array of strings that look like numbers. As noted by others, you can get that with:

```
arr = params[:value].split(',')

# Alternatively, assuming integers only
arr = params[:value].scan(/\d+/)
```

If you actually wanted an array of numbers (Integers), you could do it like so:

```
arr = params[:value].split(',').map{ |s| s.to_i }

# Or, for Ruby 1.8.7+
arr = params[:value].split(',').map(&:to_i)

# Silly alternative
arr = []; params[:value].scan(/\d+/){ |s| arr << s.to_i }
```